# Spring Data Jpa : Regarding creation and update time stamp (MySQL)

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am writing rest APIs using Spring boot and here is the structure of my entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="employee")
@Data
Public class employee extends Serializable {
    Employee attributes such as name,dept,etc

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Temporal(Temporal type.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name="create_time") 
    private Date create_time;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Temporal(Temporal type.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name="dtm_of_last_edit") 
    private Date dtmOfLastEdit;

}
```

Now the problem is every time I insert the record, JPA Auto inserts create and update time but on UPDATE (PUT CALL) I get error saying create time cannot be null...I tried sending the create time in payload but they did not help.
Am I missing something in entity ?

Comment: your entity is confusing for me as it save '@UpdateTimestamp' in create_time and '@CreationTimestamp' in dtmOfLastEdit;

Comment: Yea I typed that wrong here my bad :-(

Comment: If the field isn't available in the entity you will get an exception on updating the entity.  What you are probably doing is receiving a JSON body, deserialize that as an `Employee` and directly saving that `Employee`. What you probably need to do is to create a dedicated DTO for (de)serializing and "manually" update the `Employee` by retrieving it, updating the values and persisting it. That way you are updating the managed entity.

Comment: Yes I am directly deserialzing as Employee but why would that not work?Funny part that when I debug I see create time (if I pass in JSON ) even the. It does not persist it and give the error create_time cannot be null.

Answer (score 1):

Try Using so that this field will not be updated

```
@Column(name="create_time", updatable = false)
```

Comment: This is the right answer, even my case is different, but this solves it as well

Answer (score 0):

You better use *prePersist* and *preUpdate* method. Here is the link https://vladmihalcea.com/prepersist-preupdate-embeddable-jpa-hibernate/ so you can have better idea.

Comment: The use of those annotations makes it easier to write the timestamps, without needing to write an implementation yourself.

Comment: Hey I used the prepersist and preupdate annotation but I am still getting create_time cannot be nill..it's very strange